# MySQL Data Packet reading as "undefined" Node.js Discord.js JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently coding a Discord Bot with Node.js. I'm running the bot on a Linux (Ubuntu) server and connecting it to a database using MySQL.

I am accessing two tables with MySQL and using the data from one to search data on the other table. The purpose of this is to provide Discord users with a linked account with the ability to do `$rank detail` on Discord and have Discord provide them with their in-game Minecraft stats. This data is available through MySQL.

I am constantly receiving this same error over and over again, no matter what I try. Here is the error message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Relevant code

```js
    function linkedRankMsg() {
      var linkeddetail = database.query(detailLink,
        function(err, linkedstats, fields) {
          if(err) console.log(err);
          //linkedstats undefined... why
          var linkedUser = linkedstats[0].playerName;
          var linkedPoints = linkedstats[0].points;
          var linkedAction = linkedstats[0].actionPoints;
          var linkedTime = linkedstats[0].timePoints;
          var linkedTravel = linkedstats[0].travelPoints;
          var linkedFight = linkedstats[0].fightPoints;
```

MySQL request

```js
var detailLink = mysql.format("SELECT points,actionPoints,timePoints,travelPoints,fightPoints,playerName FROM players_rankPoints WHERE playerUUID = ?", [rawuuid]);
```

The result of logging `rawuuid` with `console.log(rawuuid);`

```js
RowDataPacket { uuid: '910643f3-2d74-436c-a8d0-4c5b227cd663' }
```

Link to full pasetbin: https://pastebin.pl/view/fc6dc5a0

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can't figure out what the error is, but I'm very new to discord.js and my experience with JavaScript is very limited.

Comment: Welcome! since you are using a callback function in `database.query`, the `await` in front of it won't work, please use `if (err) console.log(err)` as the first line inside the callback function. and share if it is giving any error or not.

Comment: Hello Raghav! I've removed all the async and await mentions in my code & moved `if(err) throw err;` to the beginning of the query functions. I am still receiving the error that `linkedstats[0].playerName` is undefined. Same error message from original post. I have updated the original post with current code.

Comment: can you please run the raw query in your DB and confirm if you are getting some data for the given query or not.?